# how do you change byebug history location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, byebug

how can I tell `byebug` to log the history to `/tmp/.byebug_history`
instead of it's default location.

I tried looking in bye bug readme but didn't find an answer

Comment: anybody know. .. .?

Answer (score 3):

Byebug looks for a `.byebugrc` file in your home directory and in your current directory. You can put lines like `set <name> <value>` in it. The possible settings are documented at https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem-settings or you can run `help set` in Byebug to get the documentation.  The setting you want is `histfile`.

So try creating `.byebugrc` in your home directory with these contents:

```
set histfile /tmp/.byebug_history
```